# How to find and update levels accordingly based on points?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, data-structures

I am creating a rails application which is like a game. So it has points and levels. For example: to become level one the user has to get atleast 100 points and again for level two the user has to reach level 2 the user has to collect 200 points. The level difference changes after every 10 levels i.e., The difference between each level changes after 10 levels always. By that I mean the difference in points between level one and two is 100 and the difference in points in level 11 and 12 is 150 and so on. There is no upper bound for levels.

Now my question is let's say a user's total points is 3150 and just got updated to 3155. What's the optimal solution to find the current level and update it if needed?

I can get a solution using while loops and again looping inside it which  will give a result in O(n^2). I need something better.

I think this code works but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it

```rb
def get_level(points)
  diff = 100
  sum = 0
  level = -1
  current_level = 0

  while level.negative?
    10.times do |i|
      current_level += 1
      sum += diff

      if points > sum
        next
      elsif points <= sum
        level = current_level
        break
      end
    end  
    diff += 50
  end
  puts level
end
```

Comment: For 101 points the function returns level 2. Do I understand correctly that from 100 to 199 inclusive level 1 must be returned?

Comment: Yes you're correct

Comment: Because levels will start from 1 and not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a `get_points` function (it should not be difficult). Then based on it `get_level` function in which it was necessary to solve the quadratic equation to find `high` value, and then calc `low`.

If you have any questions, let me know.

Check output [here](https://ideone.com/sgG2TU).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math


def get_points(level):
    high = (level + 1) // 10
    low = (level + 1) % 10
    high_point = 250 * high * high + 750 * high  # (3 + high) * high // 2 * 500
    low_point = (100 + 50 * high) * low
    return low_point + high_point


def get_level(points):
    # quadratic equation
    a = 250
    b = 750
    c = -points
    d = b * b - 4 * a * c
    x = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
    high = int(x)
    remainder = points - (250 * high * high + 750 * high)
    low = remainder // (100 + 50 * high)
    level = high * 10 + low
    return level


def main():
    for l in range(0, 40):
        print(f'{l:3d} {get_points(l - 1):5d}..{get_points(l) - 1}')

    for level, (l, r) in (
        (1, (100, 199)),
        (2, (200, 299)),
        (9, (900, 999)),
        (10, (1000, 1149)),
        (11, (1150, 1299)),
        (19, (2350, 2499)),
        (20, (2500, 2699)),
    ):
        for p in range(l, r + 1):  # for in [l, r]
            assert get_level(p) == level, f'{p} {l}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> Why did you set the value of a=250 and b = 750? Can you explain that to me please?

Let's write out every 10 level and the difference between points:

```
lvl - pnt  (+delta)
 10 - 1000 (+1000 = +100 * 10)
 20 - 2500 (+1500 = +150 * 10)
 30 - 4500 (+2000 = +200 * 10)
 40 - 7000 (+2500 = +250 * 10)
```

Divide by `500` (`10` levels * `50` difference changes) and received an arithmetic progression starting at 2:

```
 10 - 2  (+2)
 20 - 5  (+3)
 30 - 9  (+4)
 40 - 14 (+5)
```

Use [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) get points formula for `level = k * 10` equal to:

```
sum(x for x in 2..k+1) * 500 =
(2 + k + 1) * k / 2 * 500 = 
(3 + k) * k * 250 = 
250 * k * k + 750 * k
```

Now we have `points` and want to find the maximum `high` such that `point >= 250 * high^2 + 750 * high`, i. e. `250 * high^2 + 750 * high - points <= 0`. Value `a = 250` is positive and branches of the parabola are directed up. Now we find the solution of [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) `250 * high^2 + 750 * high - points = 0` and discard the real part (is `high = int(x)` in python script).

Comment: Why did you set the value of a=250 and b = 750? Can you explain that to me please?

Comment: Complemented this.

Comment: Thanks you're great!!

Comment: I'll try transforming this into ruby code. If I run into some problem I will ask you again